# How does GPS measure any plane's ground speed?

Tags: aircraft-performance, navigation, gnss

How does GPS measure an equipped airplane's ground speed assuming that the plane in question actually uses GPS as opposed to an inertial navigation system or other method?

(This was originally part of [another question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/29242/how-do-planes-measure-their-speed))

Comment: It's quite strange that the determination of the aircraft ground speed using a GPS is off-topic. It's a trivial question that may be closed, but not with the off topic criteria imho. VTR.

Comment: Could be a duplicate of [this more general question on ground speed](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/15201/1696) though.

Comment: @fooot I don't think it is, and since there is no question with a very similar title, considering the simplicity of the question, I decided to go ahead and get it knocked out on here.  Nothing says a question isn't allowed to be simple, or obvious.

Comment: From [casey's answer](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/15204/1696) to that question, `Comparing two GPS derived locations will yield a velocity vector and ground speed is its magnitude.`

Comment: So, is SE beginning to institute the marking of duplicate *answers* then?  This is *not* the same question.

Comment: @fooot It doesn't matter whether casey's answer applies here or not, we can't start marking things as dupes because of overlapping answers. See the comments on [this question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/21612/62) for a clearer example of why - in my opinion - it's a bad idea. Personally, I'd rather see 5 short, simple, obvious questions with equally simple answers than one 'generic' question that might answer everything if you read through all the answers.

Comment: @Pondlife per [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74080/257476) `If you ask a question similar to another question and it is likely to get the exact same answer, you have yourself a duplicate question.` imo, ground speed in general is not that much more complex and sufficiently covers the GPS part, there is no reason to answer it again.

Comment: What we're saying here is that an answer to [How is the actual ground speed of an airliner measured?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15201/how-is-the-actual-ground-speed-of-an-airliner-measured), in short, could be "by using GPS technology."  However, "How does GPS technology measure ground speed" is not answered by, "By using GPS technology."  Although some of the information may indeed overlap, this simplifies the search for knowledge by having a more targeted question with a more targeted answer.

Comment: A good practice is to leave the following format of comment:  "Related: [How is the actual ground speed of an airliner measured?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15201/how-is-the-actual-ground-speed-of-an-airliner-measured)

Comment: Following the close vote's logic here, "How does an inertial navigation system measure a plane's ground speed?" would also be a duplicate, even though IMHO it isn't at all.  This is really about indexing properly as to not create a wild goose chase for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly the same way that your car GPS measures your ground speed.

[image: enter link description here]
<sup>([Source](http://www.telogis.com/blog/gps-tracking-report-speeding/))</sup>

The receiver can *evaluate* the location at two successive times, and simply compute the velocity vector from differentiation. This gives a precision of several meters per second.

This velocity can be derived from the [Doppler shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect) of the [L1 carrier](http://geoconnect.com.au/gps-signals-l1-l2-l5/) frequency. This true *measure* is far more accurate, up to centimeters per second, but is less simple to implement, as the frequency shift must be smoothed over a period of time.

Reference: [How does a GNSS receiver estimate velocity?](http://www.insidegnss.com/node/4433)

Comment: I you want to relate the speed of the aircraft to the ground you have to taken into account that an aircraft is flying at 37000ft parallel to the earth. So with a bit of trigonometry you can come up with a ground speed.

Comment: @Brilsmurfffje: That's a good point! The difference between sea-level and 37,000 ft circumferences is about 70 km only, about 0.2%. Not that much, but you are right.

Comment: Not quite, in the air the actual distance travelled is not the same as distance travelled on the ground. A correction has to be made for altitude.

Answer (score 3):

GPS is primarily made to determine the position of the receiver.
Therefore, GPS uses several satellites with exactly known positions which send very precisely timed signals. From the time difference between the signals when arriving at the receiver, the own position in space can be calculate, typically given in earths coordinate system.

Get the position two times, calculate distance, divide by time difference, and you have speed.

Another way is to measure the frequency of the signals from the satellites, since it slightly varies with speed due to the Doppler effect. This is similar to the shift in pitch of the horn of a police car passing you.
This method gives you a speed value directly with your position.

As side note: 
GPS often is not that precise and gives your position with some offset. BUT the offset is mostly constant, so while the position is not correct, the distance traveled and so the speed is.