# Is there ATC audio from the Sled Driver Speed Check story?

Tags: air-traffic-control, aviation-history, sr-71

I love [this story](http://oppositelock.kinja.com/favorite-sr-71-story-1079127041), like a lot of people, but is it possible to find the actual ATC recording from that story?

Excerpt:

> Then, I heard it. The click of the mic button from the back seat. That was the very moment that I knew Walter and I had become a crew. Very professionally, and with no emotion, Walter spoke: "Los Angeles Center, Aspen 20, can you give us a ground speed check?" There was no hesitation, and the replay came as if was an everyday request. "Aspen 20, I show you at one thousand eight hundred and forty-two knots, across the ground."
>
> I think it was the forty-two knots that I liked the best, so accurate and proud was Center to deliver that information without hesitation, and you just knew he was smiling. But the precise point at which I knew that Walt and I were going to be really good friends for a long time was when he keyed the mic once again to say, in his most fighter-pilot-like voice: "Ah, Center, much thanks, we're showing closer to nineteen hundred on the money."

Comment: This would probably be pretty difficult to locate. The story doesn't give a date but I'm guessing its in the 70's. ATC audio would have been recorded on mag tape systems and frequently reused/overwritten if even recorded at all. Unfortunately the best account you are going to get of this is what you've read from the book.

Comment: Related: [How did planes measure their speed relative to the ground before GPS?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/29242/how-did-planes-measure-their-speed-relative-to-the-ground-before-gps/29256#29256). Not sure this story is true, or some pilots are such children...

Comment: 1,842 knots over the ground.... Closer to 1,900.  Great story.

Comment: @mins...some pilots are such children.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, there likely are no official recordings of this story.

Unfortunately, there was no [LiveATC.net archive](http://www.liveatc.net/archive.php) at the time, and unless there is an accident or incident, audio is not routinely archived by the FAA or NTSB.

Even when you want to request *recent* data, the FAA warns, ["Because air traffic data is routinely destroyed or disposed of in the normal course of business, time is of the essence."](http://fsims.faa.gov/wdocs/notices/n8900_195.htm) (I've seen elsewhere but couldn't find an official source that it can be anywhere from 5-45 days), so even if you could find a date of this event, you wouldn't be able to file a FOI request.